# How to convert hex to IEEE floating point python

Tags: python, struct, floating-point, hex, data-conversion

I want to convert this hex string `'8436d4ccd436d3333'` to IEEE floating point. I've try to do this with `struct.unpack` but it's requires a string argument of length 4.

```
struct.unpack('>f', binascii.unhexlify('8436d999a436e0000'))
```

I'm using this website to verify if my conversion attempts are correct : https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/ but I can't find a way to do this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, each hex string contains *two* single-precision floating-point values, not one, and the initial `8` is part of the whatever message protocol is being used, and not a part of either of those floats. With that guess, I get some plausible-looking numbers:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>ff', binascii.unhexlify('436d4ccd436d3333'))
(237.3000030517578, 237.1999969482422)
>>> struct.unpack('>ff', binascii.unhexlify('436d999a436e0000'))
(237.60000610351562, 238.0)
```

And to reinforce the plausibility, here's what I get by encoding the corresponding 1-digit-past-the-decimal-point values:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>ff', 237.3, 237.2))
b'436d4ccd436d3333'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>ff', 237.6, 238.0))
b'436d999a436e0000'
```